# Using browser detection and the body_class() function to modify css

Tags: css, theme-options

I'm using the following function, as described here:

http://www.nathanrice.net/blog/browser-detection-and-the-body_class-function/

Now when I use the following css styles, it does exactly what I want in Safari and Chrome:

```
.safari li#linkrss {margin-top: -15px;}
.chrome li#linkrss {margin-top: -15px;}
```

When I try `.gecko li#linkrss {margin-top: 0px;}` for Firefox, however, it doesn't seem to apply.  For example, when I inspect the css element using FireBug, it shows the style for Safari.  Any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: You mean the global `$is_gecko` variable is not being set to `true` in Firefox (what's the version, btw?); if this is correct then WordPress is not detecting your Firefox correctly, and assuming it is `$is_safari`. Can you dump these globals to make sure that Firefox is getting recognized as `$is_safari` instead? Do you have some header-altering Firefox plugins enabled? Disable all Firefox plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Can't tell you exactly why but that function didnt work for me either..

Finally i have found this script i have modified a little bit here: [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)**

Here it is (in your functions.php):

```
function whatBrowser() {
    //browsers
    define("UNKNOWN", 0);
    define("TRIDENT", 1);
    define("GECKO", 2);
    define("PRESTO", 3);
    define("WEBKIT", 4);
    define("VALIDATOR", 5);
    define("ROBOTS", 6);

    if(!isset($_SESSION["info"]['browser'])) {
        $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['engine'] = UNKNOWN;
        $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['version'] = UNKNOWN;
        $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['platform'] = 'Unknown';

        $navigator_user_agent = ' ' . strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

        if (strpos($navigator_user_agent, 'linux')) :
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['platform'] = 'Linux';
        elseif (strpos($navigator_user_agent, 'mac')) :
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['platform'] = 'Mac';
        elseif (strpos($navigator_user_agent, 'win')) :
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['platform'] = 'Windows';
        endif;

        if (strpos($navigator_user_agent, "trident")) {
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['engine'] = TRIDENT;
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['version'] = floatval(substr($navigator_user_agent, strpos($navigator_user_agent, "trident/") + 8, 3));
        }
        elseif (strpos($navigator_user_agent, "webkit")) {
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['engine'] = WEBKIT;
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['version'] = floatval(substr($navigator_user_agent, strpos($navigator_user_agent, "webkit/") + 7, 8));
        }
            elseif (strpos($navigator_user_agent, "presto")) {
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['engine'] = PRESTO;
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['version'] = floatval(substr($navigator_user_agent, strpos($navigator_user_agent, "presto/") + 6, 7));
        }
        elseif (strpos($navigator_user_agent, "gecko")) {
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['engine'] = GECKO;
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['version'] = floatval(substr($navigator_user_agent, strpos($navigator_user_agent, "gecko/") + 6, 9));
        }
        elseif (strpos($navigator_user_agent, "robot"))
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['engine'] = ROBOTS;
        elseif (strpos($navigator_user_agent, "spider"))
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['engine'] = ROBOTS;
        elseif (strpos($navigator_user_agent, "bot"))
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['engine'] = ROBOTS;
        elseif (strpos($navigator_user_agent, "crawl"))
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['engine'] = ROBOTS;
        elseif (strpos($navigator_user_agent, "search"))
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['engine'] = ROBOTS;
        elseif (strpos($navigator_user_agent, "w3c_validator")) 
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['engine'] = VALIDATOR;
        elseif (strpos($navigator_user_agent, "jigsaw"))
            $_SESSION["info"]['browser']['engine'] = VALIDATOR;

    echo $_SESSION['browser']['engine'];
        switch($_SESSION["info"]['browser']['engine']) {
            case UNKNOWN: echo "unknown";
            break;
            case TRIDENT: echo "trident";
            break;
            case GECKO: echo "gecko";
            break;
            case PRESTO: echo "presto";
            break;
            case WEBKIT: echo "Webkit";
            break;
            case VALIDATOR: echo "validator";
            break;
            case ROBOTS: echo "robot";
        }
    }
}
```

.
**Then just change the body tag to this:**

```
<body class="<?php whatBrowser(); ?>">
```

.
I tested it with chrome, IE & Firefox... worked gr8 for me..

Hope this Helps.
Best of luck, Sagive.